# How to remove items from a list of lists of lists of tuples, while preserving structure

Tags: python

I have a list of lists of lists of 2-tuples. It looks like this:

```
   data = [[[('hey', 9), ('how', 10), ('are', 7), ('you?', 21)], [('I', 0), ('am', 5), ('fine,', 8), ('and', 6), ('you?', 21)], [('I', 0), ('am', 5), ('fine,', 8), ('too.', 17)]], [[('My', 2), ('name', 13), ('is', 11), ('Jason,', 1), ("what's", 18), ('your', 22), ('name?', 14)], [('My', 2), ('name', 13), ('is', 11), ('Tina.', 4)], [('Nice', 3), ('to', 15), ('meet', 12), ('you.', 20)], [('Nice', 3), ('to', 15), ('meet', 12), ('you,', 19), ('too,', 16)]]]
```

How do I split this by text and integers, while preserving the structure of the original list? In essence, I want:

```
text = [[['hey', 'how', 'are', 'you?'], ['I', 'am', 'fine,', 'and', 'you?'], ['I', 'am', 'fine,', 'too.']], [['My', 'name', 'is', 'Jason,', "what's", 'your', 'name?'], ['My', 'name', 'is', 'Tina.'], ['Nice', 'to', 'meet', 'you.'], ['Nice', 'to', 'meet', 'you,', 'too,']]]

ints = [[[9, 10, 7, 21], [0, 5, 8, 6, 21], [0, 5, 8, 17]], [[2, 13, 11, 1, 18, 22, 14], [2, 13, 11, 4], [3, 15, 12, 20], [3, 15, 12,19, 16]]]
```

Comment: It looks like you have extra level - i.e. it is list of list of lists of 2-element tuples.... Is it a typo?

Comment: Thanks for the catch, its a list of list of lists of 2-element tuples. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use zip inverse

```
text = list() 
ints = list() 
for i in data: 
  text_inner = list() 
  ints_inner = list() 
  for e in i:  
    t, n = zip(*e) 
    text_inner.append(list(t)) 
    ints_inner.append(list(n)) 
  text.append(text_inner) 
  ints.append(ints_inner)
```

```
text
```

```
[[['hey', 'how', 'are', 'you?'],
  ['I', 'am', 'fine,', 'and', 'you?'],
  ['I', 'am', 'fine,', 'too.']],
 [['My', 'name', 'is', 'Jason,', "what's", 'your', 'name?'],
  ['My', 'name', 'is', 'Tina.'],
  ['Nice', 'to', 'meet', 'you.'],
  ['Nice', 'to', 'meet', 'you,', 'too,']]]
```

```
ints
```

```
[[[9, 10, 7, 21], [0, 5, 8, 6, 21], [0, 5, 8, 17]],
 [[2, 13, 11, 1, 18, 22, 14],
  [2, 13, 11, 4],
  [3, 15, 12, 20],
  [3, 15, 12, 19, 16]]]
```

### Inplace solution

If you would like to do some inplace extract (which means you may need do deepcopy if you want to get text and ints both), there might be simpler code. Even one line code possible if you combine with list comprehension.

```
for i in data:
  for j, e in enumerate(i):
    t, n = zip(*e)
    i[j] = list(t)
```

```
data
```

```
[[['hey', 'how', 'are', 'you?'],
  ['I', 'am', 'fine,', 'and', 'you?'],
  ['I', 'am', 'fine,', 'too.']],
 [['My', 'name', 'is', 'Jason,', "what's", 'your', 'name?'],
  ['My', 'name', 'is', 'Tina.'],
  ['Nice', 'to', 'meet', 'you.'],
  ['Nice', 'to', 'meet', 'you,', 'too,']]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try out like this.

```
 data = [[[('hey', 9), ('how', 10), ('are', 7), ('you?', 21)], [('I', 0), ('am', 5), ('fine,', 8), ('and', 6), ('you?', 21)], [('I', 0), ('am', 5), ('fine,', 8), ('too.', 17)]], [[('My', 2), ('name', 13), ('is', 11), ('Jason,', 1), ("what's", 18), ('your', 22), ('name?', 14)], [('My', 2), ('name', 13), ('is', 11), ('Tina.', 4)], [('Nice', 3), ('to', 15), ('meet', 12), ('you.', 20)], [('Nice', 3), ('to', 15), ('meet', 12), ('you,', 19), ('too,', 16)]]]

text = []
inst = []

for p_data in data:
    x = []
    y = []
    for q_data in p_data:
        a = []
        b = []
        for tup in q_data:
            a.append(tup[0])
            b.append(tup[1])
        x.append(a)
        y.append(b)
    text.append(x)
    inst.append(y)
print(text)
print(inst)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to walk through the list and just make new lists out of them.

```
# this will get you the list of the string 

ls = []
for list1 in data:
    for list2 in list1:
        ls.append([x[0] for x in list2])

# will get you the list of integers. 
ls = []
for list1 in data:
    for list2 in list1:
        ls.append([x[1] for x in list2])
```

if you want to avoid two different for loops.

```
words, numb = [], []
for list1 in data:
        for list2 in list1:
            words.append([x[0] for x in list2])
            numb.append([x[1] for x in list2])
print (words)
print (numb)
[['hey', 'how', 'are', 'you?'], ['I', 'am', 'fine,', 'and', 'you?'], -output - > ['I', 'am', 'fine,', 'too.'], ['My', 'name', 'is', 'Jason,', "what's", 'your', 'name?'], ['My', 'name', 'is', 'Tina.'], ['Nice', 'to', 'meet', 'you.'], ['Nice', 'to', 'meet', 'you,', 'too,']]
[[9, 10, 7, 21], [0, 5, 8, 6, 21], [0, 5, 8, 17], [2, 13, 11, 1, 18, 22, 14], [2, 13, 11, 4], [3, 15, 12, 20], [3, 15, 12, 19, 16]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Short trick with `copy.deepcopy` feature (retaining the initial "structure"):

```
from copy import deepcopy

data = [[[('hey', 9), ('how', 10), ('are', 7), ('you?', 21)], [('I', 0), ('am', 5), ('fine,', 8), ('and', 6), ('you?', 21)], [('I', 0), ('am', 5), ('fine,', 8), ('too.', 17)]], [[('My', 2), ('name', 13), ('is', 11), ('Jason,', 1), ("what's", 18), ('your', 22), ('name?', 14)], [('My', 2), ('name', 13), ('is', 11), ('Tina.', 4)], [('Nice', 3), ('to', 15), ('meet', 12), ('you.', 20)], [('Nice', 3), ('to', 15), ('meet', 12), ('you,', 19), ('too,', 16)]]]

text, ints = deepcopy(data), deepcopy(data)
for i, list_2d in enumerate(data):
    for j, list_1d in enumerate(list_2d):
        text[i][j] = [t[0] for t in list_1d]
        ints[i][j] = [t[1] for t in list_1d]

print(text)
print(ints)
```

The output:

```
[[['hey', 'how', 'are', 'you?'], ['I', 'am', 'fine,', 'and', 'you?'], ['I', 'am', 'fine,', 'too.']], [['My', 'name', 'is', 'Jason,', "what's", 'your', 'name?'], ['My', 'name', 'is', 'Tina.'], ['Nice', 'to', 'meet', 'you.'], ['Nice', 'to', 'meet', 'you,', 'too,']]]
[[[9, 10, 7, 21], [0, 5, 8, 6, 21], [0, 5, 8, 17]], [[2, 13, 11, 1, 18, 22, 14], [2, 13, 11, 4], [3, 15, 12, 20], [3, 15, 12, 19, 16]]]
```